# Adding and Removing fields to the user profile

Tags: 2010, development, user-profile

Is it possible to add and remove fields from the user profile? For example I want to add a field for LinkedIn profile and remove the Schools field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding and removing field to the User Profile you can do that via Central Administration ->Application Management -> Manage Service Application -> and click on the User Profile Service Application -> Manage User properties.

I strongly advise against removing any ootb user properties cause it might break your SharePoint 2010.

Hope this helps.