# SP2010: Using custom user profile properties on an ASPX for custom profile tab

Tags: 2010, user-profile-property, my-profile, aspx

I'm trying create a new profile tab with some customer user properties.  I've added the user properties following [these StackExchange instructions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21172/adding-and-removing-fields-to-the-user-profile).  I was also able to create a new tab with [some help from Mr. Oryszak](http://www.mikeoryszak.com/sharepoint/user-profiles-adding-a-custom-tab-and-page).  Finally, I used SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue to get the new property values to display on my new tab, as in this code:

```
Hobbies: <SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue PropertyName="Hobbies" dir="ltr" runat="server"/>
```

I'm not sure about a few things, and I think they're all related enough to be one question.

1. Is there a tag I can use to get the display name of the property rather than "hard-coding" it into an ASPX page?
2. How can I get all of the values of a multi value string property?  I just get back the first one with an ellipsis using that tag.
3. Can I make a property that acts as a lookup, or is there a way to restrict the multi-value string property to specific values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to answer all 3 questions:

1. For display name, you should be able to use ProfilePropertyDisplayName (in same namespace as ProfilePropertyValue)
2. In Central Admin, go to Your User Profile Service > Manage User Properties > Locate and Edit your multi-value user property. In edit property page, locate following setting and change it: *Maximum number of values to show before displaying ellipsis:*
3. Custom multi value User Profile property can be configured to pick a value from a term set defined in Managed Metadata Term Store. This would restrict user to choose from values defined with the term set.

Comment: Thanks @Ashish Patel.  I had no problem with the first two at all.  I can't figure out how to create a term set.  I've found several sites that talk about how (like [this one](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-managed-metadata-service-application-sharepoint-2010part-2/) and [this one](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/06/term-store-options-and-configuration/)), but no amount of right- or left-clicking in the taxonomy term store gets me a contextual menu to add a new group.  You definitely answered the question; though if you know how I can create a new group, I'd love to know!

Comment: If you don't see contextual menu to create group, ask your farm administrator to add you as a Term Store administrator (to add a new Term Group) or "Term Group Managers" to create a new Term set under the Term group that already exist.